# fineuploader jpg not working in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, jpeg, fine-uploader

I am not able to upload images with fineuploader in IE.  Works in chorme and FireFox.

Any idea why uploading jpg in IE would not work.  I noticed that chrome request object Context type is  "application/octet-stream" while IE is not.  Is this the issue if so what do i change to get the fineuploader to use this context type in request.

Thanks
        // Setup the uploader.
        if (document.getElementById('formUpload')) {
            var description = "";
            var fileName = "";
            var fileUploader = new qq.FileUploader({

```
            allowedExtensions: viewModel.AllowedFileExt(),
            element: document.getElementById('formUpload'),
            action: '../Upload/UploadHandler.ashx',
            params: {
                submissionNumber: function () {
                    submissionNumber = $("#SubmissionNumber").val();
                    return submissionNumber;
                },
                fileName: function () {
                    fileName = $(".qq-upload-file").text();
                    return fileName;
                },
                description: function () {
                    description = $("#txtAttachmentDesciption").val();
                    return description;
                }
            },
            onComplete: function (id, fileName, responseJSON) {
                $("#attachedFiles").html("");
                loadAttachments($("#Number").val());
            },
            onSubmit: function (id, fileName) {
                fileUploader.filesSelectedForUpload = 1;

            },
            autoUpload: false,
            multiple: false
        });
        fileUploader.filesSelectedForUpload = 0;
    }
```

Comment: Uploading JPGs works in IE.  Are you getting any errors?

Comment: no, not in the browser.  I get and error on the server when i try to open the uploaded image. "This is not a valid bitmap file, or its format is not currently supported. its a jpg

Comment: This would appear to be an issue with parsing the request body.  I would start by comparing the file size to the qqtotalfilesize parameter.  They should match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was server-side.
when in IE use "context.Request.Files["qqfile"].InputStream" not context.Request.InputStream

```
//if IE
var buffer = new byte[context.Request.ContentLength];
            using (var br = new BinaryReader(context.Request.Files["qqfile"].InputStream))
                br.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
//ELSE

var buffer = new byte[context.Request.ContentLength];
            using (var br = new BinaryReader(context.Request.InputStream))
                br.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```